# Why does Eric Bana give sticks to all Mossad assassins to eat before the first assassination?

Tags: plot-explanation, munich

Before the first assassination in *Munich* (2005), of Wael Zwaiter, Eric Bana gives the whole team some kind of sticks to eat. Why does he give those and what are those called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/munich.pdf) indicates that they're "drawing straws" (e.g. to determine who will actually do the dirty deed). A closer inspection of the film reveals that the straws are in fact '[grissini](http://i5.walmartimages.com/dfw/dce07b8c-8392/k2-_752d2c5a-a453-478c-801d-1e1215dc3c37.v1.jpg)'-style breadsticks, which of course ties in nicely with the fact that they're in Rome...

> **INT. A SAFEHOUSE APARTMENT IN ROME - LATE AFTERNOON**
>
> *A one-room
> apartment, windows tightly shuttered, though golden Roman afternoon
> light is leaking in. There are several mattresses on the floor, and
> street maps, surveillance photos, documents, newspapers lie scattered
> about. Avner, Carl, Hans, Robert and Steve, dressed in the clothes
> they'll wear during the hit, are kneeling on the floor in a circle.
> Carl holds four straws in his fist. Avner watches; the others draw
> straws.*
>
> *They compare. Robert has the shortest straw. The others look at him.
> He looks away, unhappy.*

[image]